# Automatic Encrypt connection string in the Web.config

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config

I have the following class to Encrypt Connection Strings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Configuration;

namespace App.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public static class ConnectionStringEncryption
    {
        private static readonly string Path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

        public static void EncryptConnString()
        {
            Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Path);
            ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
                config.Save();
            }
        }

        public static void DecryptConnString()
        {
            Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Path);
            ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
                config.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the Global.asax.cs

```
        if(!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            ConnectionStringEncryption.EncryptConnString();
```

When i try it local without  "if(!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)" works fine but when i publish I get the following error. Access to the path '...\web.config' is denied.

I don't have access to change permission to files in the server and i don't want to.

Is there another way to accomplish this without changing permission rights?

Thanks

Comment: You're writing to disk with this code.  The account running the app pool for the website doesn't have permission to do this.  So don't do it.  There are ways to protect this kind of information.  Reading and writing it to disk isn't a good idea.  Better to ask "I (think I need to) write encrypted/protected connection strings to the disk because of XYZ.  How do I do this from my website?"

Comment: What's the best way to encrypt automatic the connection string in the web.config every time i publish? It is one of the requirements. Don't want to use aspnet_regiis.exe tool.

Comment: *You can't*, unless... No, don't even want to say.  Giving your app pool identity write rights to your website directory is ***very bad.*** Why do you need to ENCRYPT it, anyhow?  Shouldn't you publish the encrypted version and simply decrypt it?  It's just weird.

Comment: Do you not trust your hosting company?  If they want your connex string, they can get it--they own your appdomain.  Attach a debugger to the damn program and they pwn yer butt.

Comment: It is require by the company.. and i can't encrypted and publish because of the Keys.. if i encrypted and publish IIS can't decrypt to get the connection string.

Comment: This makes no sense.  You publish a cleartext version, then encrypt on first request?  That's not security.  Publish an encrypted version in an app setting (NOT a connection string), then read and decode that on load.  FYI, even that's a load of BS, but it would probably be enough to cover your ass.

Comment: I understand that you can't encrypt the file on one machine and decrypt it on another if you have problems with the machine keys being different because they are used in the default encryption process. But I think you have come to the wrong conclusion that this means you have to encrypt the web.config at runtime. I have updated my answer. You need an installation process.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, the process encrypting the web.config file needs permission to write to it for obvious reasons. Maybe the question you should be asking is how to run the process as a user that has permissions to write to the file. My answer to that is, you either change the AppPool to use a user that has permissions to write the the file, or you put your code in another kind of executable that is executed, for example, at install time (as an admin) instead of at runtime.

If you're having trouble decrypting an encrypted web.config file because you don't have the proper machine keys, you should devise a process that encrypts the file on the target machine during the installation process rather than when the application runs. You need to ask more about the publish process because you should not be encrypting the file with the same account that runs the application. You should have an install process that runs on the target machine.

Comment: I am using VS2013 to deploy the app. I know WebDeploy3.5 has a feature that handle this for me. http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2013/07/09/webdeploy-3-5-rtw.aspx Do you know how to add this rule "–EnableRule:EncryptWebConfig" to the VS2013 Deployment tool?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with various versions of Visual Studio's web deployment features. I suggest you search for or ask a new question more specifically about deploying encrypted web.config files via Visual Studio or otherwise. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950978/automatically-encrypt-sections-of-web-config-after-deploy-publish