# Web.Config file encrypt not working after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, configuration, web-config

I encrypted the `web.config` file using following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EncriptSection("connectionStrings", "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
}
private void EncriptSection(string sectionName, string provider)
{
    Configuration config =
         WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);
    if (section != null && !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

after encryption web.config file,Site is running good in local system but when i publish my site and deployed into server.

Pages are not reading  the `web.config` file and giving error.When I decrypt the file and then publish the site into server site is running good on server.

How can i encrypt the file and run it into server.

```
Below is the error which i am getting now :
```

**Runtime Error**

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a `<customErrors>` tag within a `web.config` configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This `<customErrors>` tag should then have its `mode` attribute set to `Off`.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the `defaultRedirect` attribute of the application's `<customErrors>` configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

****AFTER WHEN I PUT**

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

**in configuartion then get following error****

> Parser Error Message: Failed to decrypt using provider
>   'DataProtectionConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the
>   provider: Key not valid for use in specified state. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8009000B)

Source Error:

```
Line 13:  </system.web>
Line 14:   <connectionStrings  
                 configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
Line 15:     <EncryptedData>
Line 16:     <CipherData>
Line 17:    <CipherValue>reertertertreterterterterterterterte
              rtertertertertert5345345345 </CipherValue>
```

Source File: C:\FOLDER\web.config    Line: 15

Comment: What error are you getting is very important and it is missing from your question. Please update your question

Comment: Have you tried with <customErrors mode="Off"/> to check error details

Comment: how can i try with <customErrors mode="Off"/>?

Comment: Update your web.config in server where you have hosted your website with this. <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: define mode="Off" for the customErrors and try as Rahul suggested

Comment: i GOT above ERROR after define <customErrors mode="Off"/>

Comment: What can i do for run this file

Comment: By default the machine key is used to encrypt the web config. You need to either encrypt the web.config on the server itself, specify a machine key in your web.config (which is a bit pointless if the encryption key is stored in the same file as the encrypted text) or use another method of encryption such as RSA Protected Configuration with a user key. There is a similar question about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950978/automatically-encrypt-sections-of-web-config-after-deploy-publish

Answer (score 4):

You need to publish your application with the web.config sections decrypted because the key that is used to encrypt/decrypt is machine specific.

To encrypt the web.config sections online call the `ProtectSection()` method in `Application_Start()` of `global.asax`.

So `ProtectSection()` method will do this the first time the application starts.

Comment: i am not getting you.Can you explain it more

Comment: You are publishing your web.config with sections encrypted. So encryption DataProtectionConfigurationProvider unable to decrypt it on server because generated key belong to your machine. So remove encrypted sections from web.config and add normal sections.

Comment: what is normal and encrypted section? and how can i remove encrypted section and add normal section?

Comment: This is normal connection string in web.config "<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=ServerName;Database=DB;User ID=User;Password=pass;Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>" and Encrypted is something like   <CipherValue>reert.......

Comment: ACTUALLY I NEED ENCRYPTED SO WHAT CAN I DO

Comment: @testuser Read my answer carefully. When your application will run first time on server, it will encrypt your web.config file and it will generate key on server.

Comment: You have two options. 1st use Rahuls advice (I recommend) 2nd You can create a rsa key on your local machine, export it and import it on your server (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). As Rahul says, on your dev machine you are using an machine specific rsa key to encrypt your config-sections. Your Server do not have access to this key, so the decrypting process fails.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Encryption only makes sense when it's machine specific. Else it could be easily reverted.